# Burning a multisession Data DVD from the command line for standalone player

Tags: dvd, burning

I would like to burn multi-session Data to DVD+R. I am using growisofs for that.

Previously it was working good, after one month it is giving a new error.

first session :

bhaskar@linux:~/DVD$ growisofs -speed=12  -Z /dev/sr0 -R -J -dvd-video -v /home/bhaskar/DVDdir

Executing 'genisoimage -R -J -dvd-video -v /home/bhaskar/DVDdir | builtin_dd of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'

It's done and DVD is playing good in  standalone player.

Second session :

bhaskar@linux:~/DVD$ growisofs -speed=12 -M /dev/sr0 -R -J -dvd-video -v /home/bhaskar/DVDdir
:-( media is not appendable

This is the error i am getting. While using dvd-video option in first session i am getting this error.

previously i didn't face this error while giving this command.

Please anyone help me in this.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my butler English.

---

Anyone Please help me in this , Waiting for valuable reply