# difference between mkisofs and genisoimage

Tags: command-line, execute-command

Is There any changes in mkisofs, Previously for creating iso I have used mkisofs, but now it is taking gensioimage ?

With mkisofs my work going good, but genisoimage I am facing problems with -dvd-video option.

Please any one help me

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [genisoimage man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/genisoimage), and the [mkisofs man page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_mkisofs.htm), There is really no difference. `genisoimage` is a carbon copy of `mkisofs`.

`genisoimage` is part of [cdrkit](http://www.cdrkit.org/), while `mkisofs` is part of [cdrtools](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir,You are right. but previously it was not like that. 
last time i used below one, working good with `mkisofs`. And my problem is solved.

```
growisofs -speed=1  -Z /dev/sr0 -R -J -dvd-video ~/Desktop/bhaskar/DVDdir
Executing 'mkisofs -R -J -dvd-video -v /home/bhaskar/DVDdir | builtin_dd of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0
```

Now i am using same command but executing is different,I am unable to do multi session because of this. for second time is showing media is not appendable.

```
growisofs -speed=1  -Z /dev/sr0 -R -J -dvd-video ~/Desktop/bhaskar/DVDdir
Executing 'genisoimage -R -J -dvd-video -v /home/bhaskar/DVDdir | builtin_dd of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
```

Please look into [Burning a multisession Data DVD from the command line for standalone player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557293/burning-a-multisession-data-dvd-from-the-command-line-for-standalone-player) as well.

Comment: The difference is probably in the DVD medium type. Option -dvd-video tries to close the medium. But DVD+RW, DVD-RAM, and formatted DVD-RW cannot be closed. So they stay ready for another session.